# What is maneuver Threshold in Catch-up/Break Away tests?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, vehicles

Page 204 of the PDF version of the *Shadowrun, 5th Edition* core rule book says that a driver can perform the Catch-up/Break Away action during a chase sequence. The full test description reads...

> Reaction + Vehicle Skill [Speed or Handling] (maneuver Threshold)

This seems like it should be the basic action during a chase, but I don't know what *maneuver Threshold* is in this situation. Is this a reference to the Vehicle Test Threshold Table on page 199? Isn't that information already included in the *[Speed or Handling]* limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Threshold in the Vehicle Test Threshold Table on page 199.
The French version (translation errated), p. 205, is explicit:

> test de Compétence de véhicule + Réaction [Vitesse ou Maniabilité] (seuil de manoeuvre, déterminé à l’aide de la **table Seuils de tests de pilotage, p. 200**).

Comment: I guess translator of French version was also puzzled XD. Thanks for clarification. :)

Comment: The French version is based on over 100 pages of questions and answers to CGL.